# Trigger context menu on a canvas on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, konvajs

I'm rendering content on a canvas that I want to be able to save using the browser's native "save as" context menu option.

This works well on desktop (you can go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) and right click on the green rectangle) but not on mobile (same example).

I've tried firing contextmenu events manually attached to the canvas with (using Konva and react)

```
stageRef.current?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('contextmenu', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: false,
  view: window,
  button: 2,
  buttons: 0,
  clientX: stageRef.current?.getClientRect().x,
  clientY: stageRef.current?.getClientRect().y,
}))
```

Any idea how to enable this behavior? I couldn't find any source on why it doesn't happen on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see mobile safari doesn't have such context menus for any canvas. And as I know "save as" is not a standard, so it may not work in all browsers.

As the solutions, you can make your own context menu implementation with export options.

https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Stage_Data_URL.html#page-title

https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Context_Menu.html#page-title

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to circumvent to limitations of Safari regarding direct download and share but I guess it's not possible.